# Error on LINUX OS : expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '(' token?

Tags: c++, c

Sorry for inconvenience, I don't know much about C++, i am facing this error while running on LINUX. Two errors in last two lines, and the error is the same. What am i doing wrong?

Thanks!

```
#define AOCL_ALIGNMENT 64

void *ptr = NULL;
posix_memalign(&ptr, AOCL_ALIGNMENT, 128);

free(ptr);
```

Comment: C or C++?  They are **NOT** the same language.

Comment: Which language are you compiling in? It can't be C and C++ at once. Which compiler and compiler options do you use? Which headers do you include? This is very likely related to wrong compiler options or missing includes.

Comment: Is that the whole program? Please post all relevant error messages with any question on StackOverflow.

Comment: @TamaMcGlinn He's posted the error as the subject... And, it looks like it _is_ the whole program, considering the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't call function outside of a scope in C/C++.

You have to call them from a function:

```
#define AOCL_ALIGNMENT 64

int main() {
    void *ptr = NULL;
    posix_memalign(&ptr, AOCL_ALIGNMENT, 128);

    free(ptr);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to put your code into a function, it cannot run standalone:

```
#include <cstddef>

#define AOCL_ALIGNMENT 64

int main (void) {
        void *ptr = NULL;
        posix_memalign(&ptr, AOCL_ALIGNMENT, 128);

        free(ptr);
}
```

Without the code being inside the main function, I am getting this errors then (speficially for Lundin):

```
$ g++ -O2 g.c -o g -Wall
g.c:5:15: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘(’ token
 posix_memalign(&ptr, AOCL_ALIGNMENT, 128);
               ^
g.c:7:5: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘(’ token
 free(ptr);
     ^
```

Comment: Why is this bad?

Comment: No it isn't. "NULL is not declared here", "expected declaration specifiers" etc. And we'll have to assume best intent, namely that someone using a somewhat advanced function such as `posix_memalign` already knows how to call functions in C.

Comment: Same errors in g++.

Comment: Use default g++ settings on x86. https://godbolt.org/z/MQoEyU. The first error is about missing NULL.

Comment: And the second and third error? Lundin, are you kidding me?

Comment: Anyway if this is truly the cause of the error, then the question should be closed as "simple typo", as you can't just slam some random text into a source file and expect it to compile. The OP's other question here on this site is about Open CL, they do don't seem to be a clueless newbie.

Comment: @karim Exactly the same error i encountered. But what is the difference that i can see is, "g.c:5:15:".. I don't get this with my error and the first line of your comment as well. Otherwise the same two error i faced. Still my code is running. Let's see what i get as a result.